# Scroll issue with react-select (React js)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I am using `react-select` for dropdowns. In my form I hav a array of input fields.
I have type and location as dropdowns in my form. But they can be any number of set of these dropdowns. Like below I have 2 sets.

When I select "Type" or "Location" from the second set. the page is scrolling to top, i.e to the first set of dropdowns. Why is the page scrolling to top on select of the below dropdowns. How to avoid this?

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col">
        <CreatableSelect
            options={data?.types ?? []}
            menuPortalTarget={document.body}
            styles={{
                menuPortal: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 99999 }),
            }}
            className="basic-single data-selector"
            classNamePrefix="select"
            isLoading={false}
            isClearable={false}
            isRtl={false}
            isSearchable={true}
            placeholder="Choose Type"
            name="TypeID"
            onChange={(e) => setFormData(e);}
        />
    </div>

    <div className="col">
        <CreatableSelect
            options={data?.locations ?? []}
            menuPortalTarget={document.body}
            styles={{
                menuPortal: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 99999 }),
            }}
            className="basic-single data-selector"
            classNamePrefix="select"
            isLoading={false}
            isClearable={false}
            isRtl={false}
            isSearchable={true}
            placeholder="Choose Type"
            name="LocID"
            onChange={(e) => setFormData(e);}
        />
    </div>
</div>

<div className="row">
    <div className="col">
        <CreatableSelect
            options={data?.types ?? []}
            menuPortalTarget={document.body}
            styles={{
                menuPortal: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 99999 }),
            }}
            className="basic-single data-selector"
            classNamePrefix="select"
            isLoading={false}
            isClearable={false}
            isRtl={false}
            isSearchable={true}
            placeholder="Choose Type"
            name="TypeID"
            onChange={(e) => setFormData(e);}
        />
    </div>
    <div className="col">
        <CreatableSelect
            options={data?.locations ?? []}
            menuPortalTarget={document.body}
            styles={{
                menuPortal: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 99999 }),
            }}
            className="basic-single data-selector"
            classNamePrefix="select"
            isLoading={false}
            isClearable={false}
            isRtl={false}
            isSearchable={true}
            placeholder="Choose Type"
            name="LocID"
            onChange={(e) => setFormData(e);}
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe this will be helpful https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/977#issuecomment-645605099